# runTransactionBlock currentData is null

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function trying to run transaction to update Firebase value:

```
if opponentPoints < self.points {
                        print("the host won")
                        refPoints.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

                            print("currentData", currentData.value!)
                            if var pointsToUpdate = currentData.value as? [String : Any] {
                                var pointsUp = pointsToUpdate["points"] as! Int

                                pointsUp += 3
                                pointsToUpdate["points"] = pointsUp


                                currentData.value = pointsToUpdate

                                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
                            }

                            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
                        })
```

and I have this structure:

```
 users
      uid
        points
        name
        etc.
```

The problem is that when I try to print `currentData`, I get null as result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you start a transaction, you transaction handlers is immediately invoked with the client's best guess for the current value of the data. This will most often be `null`.

The Firebase client then send the best guess (`null`) and your value to the server. The server checks, realizes that the current value is wrong and rejects the change. In that rejection, it then tells the client the current value of the location.

The Firebase client then invokes your transaction handler again, but now with the new best guess to the current value.

Long story short: your transaction handler needs to be prepared to receive `null` as the current value.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't currentData eventually return the right value at the server after the value comparison? I keep getting null although there is a value at the specified location.